# How to triangulate a 3D face?

Tags: 3d, triangulation

How can I create a 3D face out of any 3D polygon? I am looking for an algorithm or a library (free for commercial use).

My goal is to close a polygon hole on a 3D model. This functionality exists on many 3D modeling software.

The "Close a polygon hole" tool in cinema 4D:

[image: A random polygon hole.]

[image: The polygon hole closed.]

*Notes:*

- *I think there can be more than one solution to this problem, so the
  goal is to select a good solution,*
- *I know about 2D Delaunay triangulation, I do not want the 3D
  generalization which gives tetrahedron, I want triangles to create a
  face.*

Comment: I know I could project the point on a plane (computed with PCA), apply a 2D triangulation, and then use the result on my 3D vertices, but I do not know if it is a good solution (is it the method used in 3D modeling software?).

Comment: [Please explain why you vote down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) when you do.

Answer (score 1):

If you know 2d triangulation you can find the convex hull of the polygon. The same holds true for a 3d triangulation. You can walk the tetrahedrons and find the convex/concave hull.

Comment: Mh, I don't see how this helps to fill the hole of a Mesh; did I miss something?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe upload a picture? You wrote in the title about a face? What face?

Comment: I added some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try Delaunay triangulation?

> Delaunay creates a Delaunay triangulation of a set of points in 2-D or 3-D space. A 2-D Delaunay triangulation ensures that the circumcircle associated with each triangle contains no other point in its interior. This definition extends naturally to higher dimensions.

`TRI = delaunay(X,Y)
 TRI = delaunay(X,Y,Z)
 TRI = delaunay(X)`